# std::is_nothrow_invocable with member function

Tags: c++, invoke, type-traits, noexcept, member-functions

How can I check if a member function is nothrow callable in C++17?

I know my class `C` has a member function with name `f` and want to know if it is nothrow callable with an `int` as argument.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct C{
    void f(int){}
};

int main(){
    // How to use is_nothrow_invocable_v???
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_invocable_v< &C::f, int >);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might use one of the following:

```
noexcept(std::declval<C>().f(42))
```

or

```
std::is_nothrow_invocable_v<decltype(&C::f), C, int>
```

Note: you need an instance to invoke member function.

Comment: The first solution is correct, I add error messages in my original post for the second one.

Comment: Second version fixed. Missing `decltype`.